# Legacy asmx service not working when moved

Tags: web-services, asmx

I have a legacy asmx service, which I want to add to the Unit Testing coverage of our project. I created a Mockup of the asmx service and using the same proxy and serialization objects, I only change the address called by the proxy.

I can see the request object being sent, but if I step in to the function and look at the asmx code, I get a null object for the input parameter.

If I change the address back to the old service URL, it goes back to working.

I have no idea why this is happening. I have a feeling it has to do with serialization, but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check the web.config in your original application in the <webServices> section. It might be something related to protocols or something else configured for the web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the name of the variable must be the same as the string in the proxy class used to serialize the request. Who would have figured? :)